# Automatically Format Document in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, coding-style, automation

Anyway of invoking the **Edit > Advanced > Format Document"** VS command automatically when switching away from a document / routinely with a timer / on entering a document?

Its really irritating **Ctrl+E+D**'ing everytime you want to prettify your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper does this every time you close a brace, press semicolon or paste some code in. It's not quite what you're asking for, but I don't think you'll notice the difference. Oh, and it rocks in so many other ways as well.

Comment: Oh Thanks! I've got Visual Assist X so I really didn't bother about ReSharper before.

Comment: I'm surprised that VA/X doesn't do the same. I've not tried it with C# code. I tried VA/X with C++ recently, but didn't really get on with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension for Visual Studio 2013 I wrote recently. This is almost the same as the feature in Productivity power tools but also works for *.cshtml, *.xml and all formats which support the command "Format Document"

[Format Document on Save](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ea1c920-69c4-441f-9979-ccc2752dac56)